# How to get SQL translation of some functions from the DBI package

Tags: r, dbi

For example, if I want to create a table that stores the `mtcars` data set in a remote database, I can do the following with `DBI`:

```
dbWriteTable(database_connection, "MTCARS", mtcars)
```

I think behind the scenes, `DBI` (or perhaps `dbplyr`?) generates some SQL and send it to the database to complete the task. Then how can I get the SQL so that I can tweak it to better suit my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs from the `DBI` (and other R SQL) package do not necessarily correspond to just one SQL operation.  From the [documentation for DBI](https://rdrr.io/a/cran/DBI/man/dbWriteTable.html), `dbWriteTable` does the following:

> Writes, overwrites or appends a data frame to a database table, optionally converting row names to a column and specifying SQL data types for fields.

That is, depending on how you call `dbWriteTable`, using parameters such as `append` and `overwrite`, it may generate either an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or even an upsert.

Comment: So is it possible to get the SQL generated by `DBI` in plain text?

Comment: No, I don't think so, because, from reading the documentation, it is the case that functions like `dbWriteTable` use prepared statements to execute against the database.  The actual query which gets executed does not even exist until it hits the database.